# How to prevent Blogger from applying the theme styling to HTML snippets in posts?

Tags: html, css, blogger

I'm using http://hilite.me/ to style code; 
but blogger override the code colors to match the theme' colors.

example:

```html
<!-- HTML generated using hilite.me --><div style="background: #ffffff; overflow:auto;width:auto;border:solid gray;border-width:.1em .1em .1em .8em;padding:.2em .6em;"><table><tr><td><pre style="margin: 0; line-height: 125%"> 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
 9
10
11
12
13
14</pre></td><td><pre style="margin: 0; line-height: 125%"><span style="color: #0000ff">using</span> Xamarin.Forms;

<span style="color: #0000ff">namespace</span> ExpertsPartners.Controls
{
    <span style="color: #0000ff">public</span> <span style="color: #0000ff">class</span> <span style="color: #2b91af">CustomLabel</span> : Label
    {
        <span style="color: #0000ff">public</span> CustomLabel()
        {
            TextColor = (Color)Application.Current.Resources[<span style="color: #a31515">&quot;TextColor&quot;</span>];
            FontFamily = (OnPlatform&lt;<span style="color: #2b91af">string</span>&gt;)Application.Current.Resources[<span style="color: #a31515">&quot;TextFont&quot;</span>];
            FontSize = 14;
        }
    }
}
</pre></td></tr></table></div>
```

but blogger shows this: https://buildsucceeded.blogspot.com/2019/03/1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-13-14-15-16_16.html

So is there a way to make blogger not apply the theme color to a piece of HTML in a post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your css is working, it is the first wrapping tag that is not styled with a color however.

Edit: I feel i should clarify this: you can go to computed values through inspector (dev tools) and find what rule its inheriting the value from.
Change the inherited rule there or use a new rule/inline rule to overide the style appropriately, as I answered.

```
<pre style="margin: 0; line-height: 125%;color:black;">
```

```html
<!-- HTML generated using hilite.me --><div style="background: #ffffff; overflow:auto;width:auto;border:solid gray;border-width:.1em .1em .1em .8em;padding:.2em .6em;"><table><tr><td><pre style="margin: 0; line-height: 125%;color:black;"> 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
 9
10
11
12
13
14</pre></td><td><pre style="margin: 0; line-height: 125%"><span style="color: #0000ff">using</span> Xamarin.Forms;

<span style="color: #0000ff">namespace</span> ExpertsPartners.Controls
{
    <span style="color: #0000ff">public</span> <span style="color: #0000ff">class</span> <span style="color: #2b91af">CustomLabel</span> : Label
    {
        <span style="color: #0000ff">public</span> CustomLabel()
        {
            TextColor = (Color)Application.Current.Resources[<span style="color: #a31515">&quot;TextColor&quot;</span>];
            FontFamily = (OnPlatform&lt;<span style="color: #2b91af">string</span>&gt;)Application.Current.Resources[<span style="color: #a31515">&quot;TextFont&quot;</span>];
            FontSize = 14;
        }
    }
}
</pre></td></tr></table></div>
```